# Mysql Database Synchronisation with php codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, synchronization

I have a PHP codeigniter page which sends data to database every 4 seconds from a device. The page also has options to change the status of the connected device.If there is a problem with the internet connection ,i need to run the page locally and sent the data to local database and later synchronize both the remote and local database so that they are the same.I need a mechanism to synchronize the 2 databases at equal intervals of time.When the site is run live the data go to the remote database.The mechanism should sent the data from remote database to local database also at these intervals.Please share your thoughts.my local server is XAMPP.Remote server is cpanel.

Answer (score 0):

This might help:

1. have you tried using **Replication in MySQL** 
   here:
   https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/replication.html
2. You can actually solve your problem but you need to code it and it might be complex and you might also have a problem if you are using an auto increment IDs to solve this try using a custom ID for each record.